# <div> elements are displayed inline when I float them to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Basically, I have two  elements on my page, and when I float both of them to the right using `float:right;` they are displayed next to each other (inline) instead on top of each other (block).

This is the CSS for the first  element:

```
div#upgradeInfo{
    border: 2px solid white;
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

And this is the CSS for the second one.

```
div#safeTimer{
    border: 2px solid white;
    float:right;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

And here is the representation of what exactly happens :

[image: The two div's that I'm talking about are the boxes on the bottom right]

The two div's that I'm talking about are the boxes on the bottom right.
How do I display them on top of each other?
I tried doing `display:block` on both of them (and on each one individually)  but that doesn't seem to help.

I can achieve this easily using absolute positioning, but doesn't look good on all screens.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: display: inline-block; doesn't seem to work. In case you didn't understand, I want two of these "boxes" to be displayed on top of each other. Also @Rachel Gallen, even in your jsbin "output" the two <div>'s are displayed inline.

Comment: @Rachel that's exactly what he doesn't want ... Perhaps they two elements have different nesting levels, do you have like <divparent>  <div1upgradeInfo></div1upgradeInfo>  <div2safeTimer></div2safeTimer>   </divparent> ?

Comment: Try seeing how the blocks are displayed, add * {border: 2px dotted red; } to your css..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to enclose them both in a single `div`, which you then float to the right.

HTML:

```
<div id="rightCol">
    <div id="safeTimer">...</div>
    <div id="upgradeInfo">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#rightCol { float: right; }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But, how can I move the whole #rightCol <div> a little bit up?

Comment: Yeah I knew that, just, when I float something to the right side of the page, it's always in the center. Your solution works though. Thanks again!

Comment: Moving the `div` up is rather non-trivial with your setup. Because `#rightCol` is now a block element, it is floating below the other divs (the ones which show the information about the containers). To move it up, you would either have to encapsulate the other divs in a div with a restricted width, or you would have to use absolute positioning, a solution you have already stated you would like to avoid.

Comment: Thanks. But can I just display the #rightCol div as an inline element now? Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: It depends on how the other `div`s are layed-out. A JSFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Nevermind, I just floated the main content (everything on the left of the two boxes) to the left, and the the #rightCol div to the right. But now when I add new content I'll always have to float it to the left/right , which is kinda bad.

Comment: Made another change again : I wrapped the main content in a <div>, and displayed it as inline-block. I also wrapped the two boxes in a <div>,  and displayed it as inline-block too, and floated it to the right. It works wonderfully now. I can even move the box <div> up by "adding" a top margin with a negative value (margin-top: -10%;), or by increasing the bottom margin (which is not a good solution as it extends the length of the page).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your full code but my guess is you need to remove the `float:right;` and replace it with `display:inline-block;`

here is a [sample](http://jsbin.com/qujijeselu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Your JSBin doesn't work on my browser (Chrome 45.0 dev channel)

Comment: That works, but when I do that, the div's aren't displayed on the right part of the screen.

Comment: Well my code is the same as yours (I removed float : right from both of the div's and added display: inline-block to both of them) , the only thing you need is a screen shot : http://prntscr.com/7xar2w . Also they are still displayed next to each other.

Comment: put a wrapper div around all that code and add a margin-left:50%; to it - then it'll all be on the right (including the first piece of code with the three container things)

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the floating of the first div, to position the second one below the first one. Also have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp.

I've created a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/241qpda8/.

```
<div id="upgradeInfo">
    upgradeinfo
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="safeTimer">
    safeTimer
</div>
```

```
div#upgradeInfo{
    border: 2px solid black;
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 100%;
}

div#safeTimer{
    border: 2px solid black;
    float:right;
    padding: 10px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```